# How do dart streams handle back pressure and partial data?

Tags: dart, tcp, stream, network-programming

I’m learning dart and trying to implement a fairly simple protocol on top of tcp.

First, I’m not able to find any information related to back pressure in dart streams. Google just shows RxDart, but I’d rather first implement my code in core dart.

How do I tell the tcp stream (or any other stream) that my consumer is too slow. With an async stream, I’ll just keep getting updates and somewhere, some buffer will keep getting larger and larger. Is my understanding correct?

Speaking of buffers, is there a way for me to manage packets of tcp which don’t contain the full message (partial frame)? I can create my own buffer and fill it, but that means I’m allocating memory redundantly. Is there some internal buffer, where I can check its size and if it is smaller than some threshold, leave it in there. If my message is complete, read it, process it and send it to downstream consumer?

Answer (score 2):

The listener on a stream can .pause it at any time, and the source of that stream can detect that and pause adding items.  The number of items in the stream can be noticed with .length, but I'm not sure what happens if there are thousands of unread items though.

Comment: You cannot use `length` to check for unread events. Using `length` will *read and discard*  the events, and won't complete until the stream closes (and can't be used if you've already listened to the stream once). I'd take the events from the stream and immediately put them into my own `Queue`, then handle back-pressure (using `.pause()`) based on the size of that queue.