# Flutter Stream avoiding message pileup

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

So, I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/mic_stream to (atm) pull mic data so I can do processing on it and show it in the UI.  However, I suspect that the UI (or processing) takes longer than it takes to collect data, and so (presumably) data is piling up.  (A weird symptom is that it takes longer and longer between frame updates.)  Note that the stream comes from an EventChannel via [receiveBroadcastStream](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/EventChannel/receiveBroadcastStream.html).  Now, my instinct would be to discard messages if we're behind, or to set the stream to not buffer messages, or something, but I haven't found a way to do any of that.  (ARE streams buffered, btw?  If a stream isn't read from fast enough, where do messages pile up?  Does the sender block or something?)  I don't see a flag for buffering, and I don't see a way to read how many messages are waiting.  The nearest solution I can think of would be to time the interval across pulling a message and discard messages if it's below a certain interval, but that's hacky and horrible and also I don't see a way to optionally skip messages in the middle of a stream.  (E.g., I don't see flatMap, only map. Edit: it looks like `expand` is equivalent to flatMap.)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66468485/how-do-dart-streams-handle-back-pressure-and-partial-data) mentions `.pause()`, but that doesn't seem quite what I want, and doesn't explain how to detect/monitor message pileups.

How do you resolve the problem of a stream producing data faster than you can consume it?

Comment: For now I'm just dropping 2 out of 3 messages, using `expand`, but I'd prefer to be able to tell when it's necessary and adapt accordingly.